# Disable CSV downloads in Active Admin

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

I am using the Active Admin gem and I would like to hide or remove the links on the index page of each model allowing users to download data as CSV, XML or JSON. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 24):

There is now an option `:download_links` on the index method, so you omit the download links if you want.

For example:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Post do
  index :download_links => false do
    # whatever
  end
end
```

Comment: Hey @kimos, nice first answer.

Comment: You can even set it globally in config/initalizers/active_admin.rb

Answer (score 7):

You should use it as a option of index, but do not separate it from the column functions. Use it like this.

```
ActiveAdmin.register Post do
  index :download_links => false do
    column :title
    column :body
  end
end
```

Do not use it like this.This will let all your table columns is displayed, not the only that you specified by column function

```
index download_links: false
index do
  column :title
  column :body
end
```

Answer (score 6):

Since you asked how to remove download links on each page, so the best to do say is to add the following line in **config/initializers/active_admin.rb** file.

```
config.namespace :admin do |admin|
  admin.download_links = false
end
```

You can also specify which options you would like to have for downloading the data, like:

```
config.namespace :admin do |admin|
  admin.download_links = [:pdf] # Now, it will only show PDF option.
end
```

Note: Please don't forget to restart your server after you modify a config file.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to the css fix above is this monkey patch:

```
module ActiveAdmin
  module Views
    class PaginatedCollection
      def build_download_format_links(*args)
        ''
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone hitting this page more recently who isn't happy with the answers, this works for me:

1: Hide all downloads:

`app/admin/your_model.rb`

```
ActiveAdmin.register YourModel do
  index download_links: [nil]
  ...
```

2: Show only JSON. (Because why would you ever need anything else?):

`app/admin/your_model.rb`

```
ActiveAdmin.register YourModel do
  index download_links: [:json]
  ...
```

3: It's an array y'all, so you can add in XML, CSV and more:

`app/admin/your_model.rb`

```
ActiveAdmin.register YourModel do
  index download_links: [:json, :xml, :csv]
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

ActiveAdmin doesn't allow this to be configured. Hack it using CSS.

In `app/assets/stylesheets/active_admin.css.scss`

```
.index #active_admin_content #index_footer {
  color: white;  // Hides the 'Download text'. Pagination links are styled on their own
  a {
    display: none; // Hides the CSV .. links
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much, Akshay. Another solution that disables them altogether is at https://gist.github.com/1641438. But it only worked for me when I started working off the latest master on Github.