# How to stop downloads in ActiveAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, cancan

I would like only certain users to be able to download CSV, JSON, etc.

If I block the links. going to /admin/link.csv will still allow the user to download the file. How can I prevent this?

Comment: How did you block the links? You could also try patching [like mentioned here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10184033/980524).

Comment: @wpp I just tried that, it doesn't stop someone tacking .csv to the end of the url